# What is the difference in methodologies of returning data to the view between Rails and Django?

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, django

I am torn on which way is correct to return data to the front-end. Rails does it one way, while Django does it another way.

-- Rails methodology --
Controller:

```
QuizController
  def action
     @quizzes = Quiz.all
     @users = User.all
     render "action"
  end
end
```

action.haml:

```
= @quizzes.to_a
= @users.to_a
```

* VERSUS **********

--Django methodology (written in Ruby)--

Controller:

```
QuizController
  def action
     quizzes = Quiz.all
     users = User.all
     render "action", locals: {quizzes: quizzes, users: users}
  end
end
```

action.haml:

```
= quizzes.to_a
= users.to_a
```

Seems like the Django way is more explicit and lets the front-end dev know which objects they have access to right away.  The Rails way seems more difficult to process, and allows for more mistakes to be created.

I actually think that I"m looking for a Rails solution that does something similar to the Model View ViewModel 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel' in .NET

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by "difficult to process," your front end dev is going to  have to look at the controller either way. If you're declaring a lot of variables in your controller actions in either framework you're probably doing it wrong, so explicitness shouldn't really be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for view models for rails you should look at Draper: https://github.com/drapergem/draper

It's pretty easy to roll your own as well, there is nothing to stop you from only exposing one object to your Rails views.

Answer (score 1):

The Django trick that simulates Rails's "automagic variables" is...

```
quizzes = Quiz.objects.all()
users = User.objects.all()
return render_to_response('about.html', locals())
```